# undefined local variable or method `page'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using rails. I execute a ruby script using following command. And it gives an error. what'd be problem? If I remove "page.should have_content('Demo App')", then it works properly!

```
 bundle exec rspec spec/requests/test_pages_spec.rb
```

---

```
 Failures:

1) Test pages Home page should have the content 'Demo App'
 Failure/Error: page.should have_content('Demo App')
 NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `page' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0xa60d538>
 # ./spec/requests/test_pages_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.27788 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/test_pages_spec.rb:7 # Test pages Home page should have the content 'Demo App'
```

test_pages_spec.rb is as follow:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Test pages" do

describe "Home page" do

   it "should have the content 'Demo App'" do
    visit '/test_pages/home'
    page.should have_content('Demo App')
   end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this problem. If I use webrat and capybara both then I cannot see result proper. So I have to remove  **gem 'webrat'**  from Gemfile and type  **bundle update**  and use following command and problem is solved!

```
bundle exec rspec spec/requests/test_pages_spec.rb
```